# Compare a series of intervals with itself

Tags: python, pandas, series

For a series of [`Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html)

```
s = pd.Series([
    pd.Interval(left=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), right=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-05'), closed='both'), 
    pd.Interval(left=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), right=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-02'), closed='both'), 
    pd.Interval(left=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-04'), right=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-05'), closed='both'), 
])
```

I want to check for every interval pair - like an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) - if it is overlapping or not. For that [`Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) offers the method [`overlaps()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.overlaps.html).

The result should be a `l x l` matrix/data frame for a Series of length `l` containing if the pair overlaps or not. For example:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|                          | [2020-01-01, 2020-01-05] | [2020-01-01, 2020-01-02] | [2020-01-04, 2020-01-05] |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| [2020-01-01, 2020-01-05] | True                     | True                     | True                     |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| [2020-01-01, 2020-01-02] | True                     | True                     | False                    |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| [2020-01-04, 2020-01-05] | True                     | False                    | False                    |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Because the series is quite large, I'm looking for a more performant and efficient way than [`itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html#pandas.IntervalIndex), to be able to get `right` and `left` bounds easily and use numpy [`ufunc.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) with `greater_equal` and [`less_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal).

```
import numpy as np

#work with IntervalIndex
idx = pd.IntervalIndex(s)
#get right and left bounds
right = idx.right
left = idx.left

#create the boolean of True and False
arr = np.greater_equal.outer(right, left) & np.less_equal.outer(left, right)

#create the dataframe if needed
print (pd.DataFrame(arr, index=s.values, columns=s.values))
                          [2020-01-01, 2020-01-05]  [2020-01-01, 2020-01-02]  \
[2020-01-01, 2020-01-05]                      True                      True   
[2020-01-01, 2020-01-02]                      True                      True   
[2020-01-04, 2020-01-05]                      True                     False   

                          [2020-01-04, 2020-01-05]  
[2020-01-01, 2020-01-05]                      True  
[2020-01-01, 2020-01-02]                     False  
[2020-01-04, 2020-01-05]                      True
```

It seems that you could also use [`overlaps`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.overlaps.html#pandas.IntervalIndex.overlaps) on the IntervalIndex and do something like:

```
np.stack([idx.overlaps(interval) for interval in idx])
#or for dataframe
pd.DataFrame([idx.overlaps(interval) for interval in idx], 
             index=s.values, columns=s.values)
```